# how to make jmeter Thread group sleep till all the threads in other thread group are active

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 thread groups in jmeter project and when I run it, thread group2 starts paralelly along with threadgroup1. Is there a way I can make threadgroup2 to wait till all the threads in tg1 become active/running state?

Basically in threadgroup1 I am inducing the load and in threadgroup2 I have a thread which is integrated with selenium to capture the actual response time when the load is applied. Currently well before all the threads in tg1 are fired tg2 starts.

Comment: I don't know how you integrate with JMeter, but if I had two Thread Groups I would utilize a CountdownLatch (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).  You can block on the latch (on a separate thread) until all the Threads from Group1 have decremented the latch and are running.  Once unblocked, that separate thread can start the second group.

Comment: @Vikaram Jere, did you try with 'Startup delay' in thread group 2? It does not help?

Comment: I would not depend on a fixed delay to start threads.  You're better off using some sort of well structured signaling.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest option would be to use the `Startup delay` in the Thread Group 2. delay period would be the rampup period (+ few seconds) of Thread group 1. By this time, JMeter would have started all the threads in the Thread Group 1.

Another approach would be to use to beanshell in the `Thread Group 2` to calculate the total active threads of Thread Group 1. (assuming you only have 2 thread groups)

`org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getNumberOfThreads()` gives total active threads of the Jmeter test.

`ctx.getThreadGroup().numberOfActiveThreads()` - gives the active threads in the current thread group.

so,

```
int grp1_thread_count = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getNumberOfThreads() - ctx.getThreadGroup().numberOfActiveThreads();
```

In the Thread group 2, use an `If controller` to check for the no of active threads of Thread Group 1 by using the value of `grp1_thread_count` to send the requests.